# How to position my image below and to the right of my text?

Tags: html, css

I have the following design:
[image]

Notice the signature on the bottom under the quotation. Its very nicely placed on the right aligned with the text.

Here is my html css version so far:

[image]

I'm having trouble figuring out the correct way to get the signature over to the right and aligned with the right of the quotation.

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="header">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="images/top-logo.png" alt="ProvenWord Logo">
                </div>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Proofreading</li>
                    <li>Editing</li>
                    <li>About</li>
                    <li>How it works</li>
                    <li>FAQ</li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!--close header -->
            <div class="tagline">
                <div class="section-container">
                    <h1><span>Transform your written</span> work into a <strong>masterpiece<strong></h1>
                    <a href="freequote.html" class="button">Free Quote</a>
                    <p class="first-quote">"Your proofreading assistance has enabled me to successfully complete my dissertation with greater ease."</p>
                    <img src="images/sudthida-signature.png" alt="Sudthida's Signature">
                    <p class="first-quote school">Sudthida P. Ph.D in Educational Research - King's College University of London</p>
                </div><!--close section-container-->
            </div><!--close tagline-->              
        </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my css:

```
html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, p, ol, ul, li, a, div {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
}


/*----------------------------*/
/*----- Tag Declarations -----*/
/*--------------------------- */

body {
    font-family: "Sinkin Sans", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


h1{
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.3;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h2 strong {
    font-weight: 600;
}

p {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 140%;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 48px;  /*setting this to the button height makes the text centered */
    height: 48px;
    width: 185px;
    background: #ffd000;
    border: 2px solid #b59400;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 100;x;
    border-radius: 60px;
}

a.button {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

a.button:hover {
    background: #feef00;
}


li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    text-indent: 1.5em;
    background-image: url(images/check.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.section-container {
    width: 520px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*--------------------------*/
/*----- Header Section -----*/
/*--------------------------*/

.header {
    padding: 25px 0px 32px 48px;
}


.logo img {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 130px;
}

.nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 32px;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
}


/*---------------------------*/
/*----- Tagline Section -----*/
/*---------------------------*/

.tagline {
    background: #abdfe8 url(images/bg-tagline.png) no-repeat;
    height: 450px;
    text-align: center;
}


.section-container h1 {
    padding-top: 130px;

}

.section-container h1 span {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.section-container .button {
    margin: 40px 0 40px 0;
}


.first-quote {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 25px 10px 25px;
}

.section-container img {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}


.section-container .school {
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I have used the margin property to move the image over but I thought margins were used to create space between block elements. I don't want to hack my way to the layout, I want to understand how this works and what is the correct way to use the different properties in css.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use float to align the image to the right, combined with margin to place it exactly where needed, then just clear the text below the image.

I've commented the changes in your CSS below.

```css
html,
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p,
ol,
ul,
li,
a,
div {
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
}
/*----------------------------*/

/*----- Tag Declarations -----*/

/*--------------------------- */

body {
  font-family: "Sinkin Sans", Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 28px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.3;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
h2 strong {
  font-weight: 600;
}
p {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 140%;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 48px;
  /*setting this to the button height makes the text centered */
  height: 48px;
  width: 185px;
  background: #ffd000;
  border: 2px solid #b59400;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  x;
  border-radius: 60px;
}
a.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}
a.button:hover {
  background: #feef00;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-indent: 1.5em;
  background-image: url(images/check.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.section-container {
  width: 520px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/*--------------------------*/

/*----- Header Section -----*/

/*--------------------------*/

.header {
  padding: 25px 0px 32px 48px;
}
.logo img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 130px;
}
.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 32px;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 200;
}
/*---------------------------*/

/*----- Tagline Section -----*/

/*---------------------------*/

.tagline {
  background: #abdfe8 url(images/bg-tagline.png) no-repeat;
  height: 450px;
  text-align: center;
}
.section-container h1 {
  padding-top: 130px;
}
.section-container h1 span {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.section-container .button {
  margin: 40px 0 40px 0;
}
.first-quote {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 25px 10px 25px;
}
.section-container img {
  display: block;
  float: right; /* USE FLOAT */
  margin-right: 1.8em; /* WITH MARGIN TO GIVE THE CORRECT POSITION */
}
.section-container .school {
  clear: both; /* CLEAR THE FLOATED IMAGE */
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="images/top-logo.png" alt="ProvenWord Logo">
  </div>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Proofreading</li>
    <li>Editing</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>How it works</li>
    <li>FAQ</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--close header -->
<div class="tagline">
  <div class="section-container">
    <h1><span>Transform your written</span> work into a <strong>masterpiece<strong></h1>
    <a href="freequote.html" class="button">Free Quote</a>
    <p class="first-quote">"Your proofreading assistance has enabled me to successfully complete my dissertation with greater ease."</p>
    <img src="images/sudthida-signature.png" alt="Sudthida's Signature">
    <p class="first-quote school">Sudthida P. Ph.D in Educational Research - King's College University of London</p>
  </div>
  <!--close section-container-->
</div>
<!--close tagline-->
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Is this better than just giving a margin of 430px to the right?

Comment: You could do either one really. :)